# What is the song playing in Naruto Shippuden episode 121 when Itachi and Kisame are walking together?

Tags: naruto, music

In *Naruto Shippuden* episode 121, it starts playing at 0:40 or so when Itachi and Kisame are walking together.

Comment: welcome to Anime and Manga. the site you linked to is an illegal streaming site as such i have removed the link. in future please use a legal source if you want to link to videos, example sources can be found in [this list](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/923/1587)

Answer (score 0):

The song you're referring to is Itachi's theme song. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXLfg2ry_F4